# Angular.js - How to use directive in another directive?

Tags: templates, angularjs, svg, directive, snap.svg

I want to use directive in another directive.

The parent directive uses child directive in its template.

Here is my code.

Html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <svg>
            <my-line></my-line>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[
    'myController',
    'myDirectives'
]);

//Controller
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);
myControllers.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.line = [
        { nodeId:'1'},
        { nodeId:'2'},
        { nodeId:'3'}
    ]
});

//Directives
var myDirectives = angular.module('myDirectives',[]);

myDirectives.directive('myLine',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:
            '<g ng-repeat="node in line">' +
                '<my-node node="{{node}}"></my-node>' + 
            '</g>'
    };
});

myDirectives.directive('myNode',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            node:'=node'
        },
        template:
            '<text x="0" y="0">{{node.nodeId}</text>'
    }
});
```

Here is jsfiddle link.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maasaamiichii/D44us/1/)

But the child directive isn't show.

What should I do?

Comment: Check this out [JSFiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/72PjQSOlckGyUQnH7zOA?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is a good example using parent directive. But I want use child directive in parent template.

Comment: There is a difference between DOM nodes and SVG nodes. Angular is creating DOM nodes. Check this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/nP5JSuRuBMw/Wkv4DGMrtEUJ

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your fiddle. I fixed them up.

First up at the top it should be

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[
    'myControllers',
    'myDirectives'
]);
```

Next up, in the myNode directive it should be

```
'<text x="0" y="0">{{node.nodeId}}</text>'
```

After that, I added replace to both both directives configurations.

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vNF9L/

Now, nothing is displayed, but if you inspect the dom you'll see everything is outputted like how you wanted.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry that my code was wrong. Thank you for your modification.

Comment: No need to apologise. As for SVG I am not familiar with it, I merely answered the angular part of your question.